# Reading .txt file with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a currency.txt file which has the bellow data. This file needs to read and the function should change the value according to the rate defined in the currency.txt file.

Can we read and implement the calculation for changing the rates according to the data in file?

Can we read the file the data without changing it to json file? and how?

```
AED: 3.673158
AFN: 66.5531
ALL: 122.0891
AMD: 473.447501
ANG: 1.77635
AOA: 165.574831
ARS: 15.1542
AUD: 1.3111
AWG: 1.7925
AZN: 1.637275
BAM: 1.743055
BBD: 2
BDT: 78.48426
BGN: 1.744303
BHD: 0.377045
BIF: 1664.285005
BMD: 1
BND: 1.35824
BOB: 6.918732
BRL: 3.239768
BSD: 1
BTC: 0.001658952537
BTN: 66.7716
BWP: 10.44955
BYN: 1.9317
BYR: 20026.25
BZD: 2.003485
CAD: 1.315362
CDF: 976.003512
CHF: 0.970299
CLF: 0.024942
CLP: 660.9122
CNY: 6.670311
COP: 2911.736667
CRC: 550.991395
CUC: 1
CUP: 24.728383
CVE: 98.237901
CZK: 24.06994
DJF: 177.6895
DKK: 6.640365
DOP: 46.14923
DZD: 109.20114
EEK: 13.946275
EGP: 8.876718
ERN: 15.345
ETB: 22.18501
EUR: 0.89055
FJD: 2.047283
FKP: 0.771235
GBP: 0.771235
GEL: 2.31522
GGP: 0.771235
GHS: 3.989695
GIP: 0.771235
GMD: 42.59622
GNF: 9085.73
GTQ: 7.521723
GYD: 205.929
HKD: 7.756197
HNL: 22.84758
HRK: 6.675303
HTG: 65.352987
HUF: 272.4474
IDR: 13078.15
ILS: 3.760562
IMP: 0.771235
INR: 66.684569
IQD: 1165.1165
IRR: 30073
ISK: 114.4302
JEP: 0.771235
JMD: 127.627199
JOD: 0.709036
JPY: 100.997801
KES: 101.19139
KGS: 68.521502
KHR: 4094.055
KMF: 438.793335
KPW: 899.91
KRW: 1102.923325
KWD: 0.301276
KYD: 0.824873
KZT: 338.062999
LAK: 8108.6975
LBP: 1509.98835
LKR: 146.360001
LRD: 91.75
LSL: 13.69269
LTL: 3.062908
LVL: 0.624468
LYD: 1.380564
MAD: 9.715581
MDL: 19.74908
MGA: 3052.593333
MKD: 54.86438
MMK: 1240.295
MNT: 2254.463333
MOP: 7.991731
MRO: 355.854167
MTL: 0.683602
MUR: 35.430863
MVR: 15.28
MWK: 718.233316
MXN: 19.76579
MYR: 4.118866
MZN: 77.150002
NAD: 13.66729
NGN: 313.263
NIO: 28.97315
NOK: 8.115266
NPR: 106.6434
NZD: 1.38045
OMR: 0.384972
PAB: 1
PEN: 3.353345
PGK: 3.16725
PHP: 48.0975
PKR: 104.802999
PLN: 3.828987
PYG: 5576.745
QAR: 3.641512
RON: 3.962603
RSD: 109.910661
RUB: 64.00919
RWF: 800.581171
SAR: 3.750628
SBD: 7.839816
SCR: 13.19386
SDG: 6.107271
SEK: 8.542465
SGD: 1.358757
SHP: 0.771235
SLL: 5648.5
SOS: 586.352333
SRD: 7.73675
STD: 21844.6
SVC: 8.747333
SYP: 214.030002
SZL: 13.66699
THB: 34.64227
TJS: 7.877575
TMT: 3.468367
TND: 2.203765
TOP: 2.23775
TRY: 2.962368
TTD: 6.698899
TWD: 31.35474
TZS: 2181.12
UAH: 25.97589
UGX: 3385.153333
USD: 1
UYU: 28.50672
UZS: 2991.175
VEF: 9.977606
VND: 22330.95
VUV: 105.893334
WST: 2.5135
XAF: 584.351655
XAG: 0.05081571
XAU: 0.00075126
XCD: 2.69902
XDR: 0.71484
XOF: 586.950754
XPD: 0.001488
XPF: 106.378
XPT: 0.000882
YER: 250.204
ZAR: 13.69108
ZMK: 5253.075255
ZMW: 10.037938
ZWL: 322.387247
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".currency-target").change(function() {
    //alert();
    $.ajax({
      url: "currency.txt",
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
        //alert(3);
        var CurrVal = $('.currency-target :selected').val();
        //alert(CurrVal);
        if (CurrVal == data.) {
          alert();
        }

      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.usdAmt {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: DarkGray;
}
.currencyValue {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin 0px 5px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  height: 1.4em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.currencyTarget {
  height: 1.8em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get">
  <p class="usdAmt">1 US Dollar(s) equals</p>
  <p class="currencyValue"></p>
  <p>
    <input class="exchAmt" type="text" style="width: 4em;margin-right:0.5em; text-align:right;" value="1" />
    <select class="currency-target" style="font-size: 1.5em">
      <option value="">Select a currency</option>
      <option value="AFN">Afghanistan Afghani</option>
      <option value="ALL">Albanian Lek</option>
      <option value="DZD">Algerian Dinar</option>
      <option value="AOA">Angolan Kwanza</option>
      <option value="ARS">Argentine Peso</option>
      <option value="AMD">Armenian Dram</option>
      <option value="AWG">Aruban Florin</option>
      <option value="AUD">Australian Dollar</option>
      <option value="AZN">Azerbaijan New Manat</option>
      <option value="BSD">Bahamian Dollar</option>
      <option value="BHD">Bahraini Dinar</option>
      <option value="BDT">Bangladeshi Taka</option>
      <option value="BBD">Barbados Dollar</option>
      <option value="BYR">Belarusian Ruble</option>
      <option value="BZD">Belize Dollar</option>
      <option value="BMD">Bermudian Dollar</option>
      <option value="BTN">Bhutan Ngultrum</option>
      <option value="BOB">Bolivian Boliviano</option>
      <option value="BAM">Bosnian Mark</option>
      <option value="BWP">Botswana Pula</option>
      <option value="BRL">Brazilian Real</option>
      <option value="GBP">British Pound</option>
      <option value="BND">Brunei Dollar</option>
      <option value="BGN">Bulgarian Lev</option>
      <option value="BIF">Burundi Franc</option>
      <option value="XOF">CFA Franc BCEAO</option>
      <option value="XAF">CFA Franc BEAC</option>
      <option value="XPF">CFP Franc</option>
      <option value="KHR">Cambodian Riel</option>
      <option value="CAD">Canadian Dollar</option>
      <option value="CVE">Cape Verde Escudo</option>
      <option value="KYD">Cayman Islands Dollar</option>
      <option value="CLP">Chilean Peso</option>
      <option value="CNY">Chinese Yuan/Renminbi</option>
      <option value="COP">Colombian Peso</option>
      <option value="KMF">Comoros Franc</option>
      <option value="CDF">Congolese Franc</option>
      <option value="CRC">Costa Rican Colon</option>
      <option value="HRK">Croatian Kuna</option>
      <option value="CUC">Cuban Convertible Peso</option>
      <option value="CUP">Cuban Peso</option>
      <option value="CYP">Cyprus Pound</option>
      <option value="CZK">Czech Koruna</option>
      <option value="DKK">Danish Krone</option>
      <option value="DJF">Djibouti Franc</option>
      <option value="DOP">Dominican R Peso</option>
      <option value="XCD">East Caribbean Dollar</option>
      <option value="EGP">Egyptian Pound</option>
      <option value="SVC">El Salvador Colon</option>
      <option value="EEK">Estonian Kroon</option>
      <option value="ETB">Ethiopian Birr</option>
      <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
      <option value="FKP">Falkland Islands Pound</option>
      <option value="FJD">Fiji Dollar</option>
      <option value="GMD">Gambian Dalasi</option>
      <option value="GEL">Georgian Lari</option>
      <option value="GHS">Ghanaian New Cedi</option>
      <option value="GIP">Gibraltar Pound</option>
      <option value="XAU">Gold (oz)</option>
      <option value="GTQ">Guatemalan Quetzal</option>
      <option value="GNF">Guinea Franc</option>
      <option value="GYD">Guyanese Dollar</option>
      <option value="HTG">Haitian Gourde</option>
      <option value="HNL">Honduran Lempira</option>
      <option value="HKD">Hong Kong Dollar</option>
      <option value="HUF">Hungarian Forint</option>
      <option value="ISK">Iceland Krona</option>
      <option value="INR">Indian Rupee</option>
      <option value="IDR">Indonesian Rupiah</option>
      <option value="IRR">Iranian Rial</option>
      <option value="IQD">Iraqi Dinar</option>
      <option value="ILS">Israeli New Shekel</option>
      <option value="JMD">Jamaican Dollar</option>
      <option value="JPY">Japanese Yen</option>
      <option value="JOD">Jordanian Dinar</option>
      <option value="KZT">Kazakhstan Tenge</option>
      <option value="KES">Kenyan Shilling</option>
      <option value="KWD">Kuwaiti Dinar</option>
      <option value="KGS">Kyrgyzstanian Som</option>
      <option value="LAK">Lao Kip</option>
      <option value="LVL">Latvian Lats</option>
      <option value="LBP">Lebanese Pound</option>
      <option value="LSL">Lesotho Loti</option>
      <option value="LRD">Liberian Dollar</option>
      <option value="LYD">Libyan Dinar</option>
      <option value="LTL">Lithuanian Litas</option>
      <option value="MOP">Macau Pataca</option>
      <option value="MKD">Macedonian Denar</option>
      <option value="MGA">Malagasy Ariary</option>
      <option value="MWK">Malawi Kwacha</option>
      <option value="MYR">Malaysian Ringgit</option>
      <option value="MVR">Maldive Rufiyaa</option>
      <option value="MTL">Maltese Lira</option>
      <option value="MRO">Mauritanian Ouguiya</option>
      <option value="MUR">Mauritius Rupee</option>
      <option value="MXN">Mexican Peso</option>
      <option value="MDL">Moldovan Leu</option>
      <option value="MNT">Mongolian Tugrik</option>
      <option value="MAD">Moroccan Dirham</option>
      <option value="MZN">Mozambique New Metical</option>
      <option value="MMK">Myanmar Kyat</option>
      <option value="ANG">NL Antillian Guilder</option>
      <option value="NAD">Namibia Dollar</option>
      <option value="NPR">Nepalese Rupee</option>
      <option value="NZD">New Zealand Dollar</option>
      <option value="NIO">Nicaraguan Cordoba Oro</option>
      <option value="NGN">Nigerian Naira</option>
      <option value="KPW">North Korean Won</option>
      <option value="NOK">Norwegian Kroner</option>
      <option value="OMR">Omani Rial</option>
      <option value="PKR">Pakistan Rupee</option>
      <option value="PAB">Panamanian Balboa</option>
      <option value="PGK">Papua New Guinea Kina</option>
      <option value="PYG">Paraguay Guarani</option>
      <option value="PEN">Peruvian Nuevo Sol</option>
      <option value="PHP">Philippine Peso</option>
      <option value="PLN">Polish Zloty</option>
      <option value="QAR">Qatari Rial</option>
      <option value="RON">Romanian New Lei</option>
      <option value="RUB">Russian Rouble</option>
      <option value="RWF">Rwandan Franc</option>
      <option value="WST">Samoan Tala</option>
      <option value="STD">Sao Tome/Principe Dobra</option>
      <option value="SAR">Saudi Riyal</option>
      <option value="RSD">Serbian Dinar</option>
      <option value="SCR">Seychelles Rupee</option>
      <option value="SLL">Sierra Leone Leone</option>
      <option value="XAG">Silver (oz)</option>
      <option value="SGD">Singapore Dollar</option>
      <option value="SKK">Slovak Koruna</option>
      <option value="SIT">Slovenian Tolar</option>
      <option value="SBD">Solomon Islands Dollar</option>
      <option value="SOS">Somali Shilling</option>
      <option value="ZAR">South African Rand</option>
      <option value="KRW">South-Korean Won</option>
      <option value="LKR">Sri Lanka Rupee</option>
      <option value="SHP">St Helena Pound</option>
      <option value="SDG">Sudanese Pound</option>
      <option value="SRD">Suriname Dollar</option>
      <option value="SZL">Swaziland Lilangeni</option>
      <option value="SEK">Swedish Krona</option>
      <option value="CHF">Swiss Franc</option>
      <option value="SYP">Syrian Pound</option>
      <option value="TWD">Taiwan Dollar</option>
      <option value="TZS">Tanzanian Shilling</option>
      <option value="THB">Thai Baht</option>
      <option value="TOP">Tonga Pa'anga</option>
      <option value="TTD">Trinidad/Tobago Dollar</option>
      <option value="TND">Tunisian Dinar</option>
      <option value="TRY">Turkish New Lira</option>
      <option value="TMM">Turkmenistan Manat</option>
      <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
      <option value="UGX">Uganda Shilling</option>
      <option value="UAH">Ukraine Hryvnia</option>
      <option value="UYU">Uruguayan Peso</option>
      <option value="AED">United Arab Emir Dirham</option>
      <option value="VUV">Vanuatu Vatu</option>
      <option value="VEB">Venezuelan Bolivar</option>
      <option value="VND">Vietnamese Dong</option>
      <option value="YER">Yemeni Rial</option>
      <option value="ZMK">Zambian Kwacha</option>
      <option value="ZWD">Zimbabwe Dollar</option>
    </select>
</form>
<p class="feedback"></p>
```

Comment: specify the `url` correctly...you cant call a text file like that using ajax

Answer (score 1):

You just need to parse that file like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var _converted = {};
  var _currency_txt;

  $(".currency-target").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "currency.txt",
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
        _currency_txt = data;

        var CurrVal = $('.currency-target :selected').val();
        var rate = get_currency(CurrVal);
      }
    });
  });

  function get_currency(short_name)
  {
    var list = get_currencies();
    if (typeof list[short_name] !== 'undefined') {
      return list[short_name];
    }
  }

  function get_currencies()
  {
    if ($.isEmptyObject(_converted)) {
      var _tmp = _currency_txt.split("\n");
      for(var i = 0; i < _tmp.length; i++) {
        var _curr = _tmp.split(':');
        _converted[_curr[0]] = parseFloat(_curr[1]);
      }
    }
    return _converted;
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Your questions:

> Can we read and implement the calculation for changing the rates
>   according to the data in file?

You can, since the format of your `currency.txt` file data seems fixed. However you'll have to parse your `currency.txt` file data everytime you'll want to get a specific currency from it. (*Not very optimal...*)

> Can we read the file the data without changing it to json file? and
>   how?

Well when you get the data (*I hope you're sending the data and not sending the file*), it'll just be a big `string`.

```js
var data = "AED: 3.673158 AFN: 66.5531 ALL: 122.0891 AMD: 473.447501 ANG: 1.77635 AOA: 165.574831 ARS: 15.1542 AUD: 1.3111 AWG: 1.7925 AZN: 1.637275 BAM: 1.743055 BBD: 2 BDT: 78.48426 BGN: 1.744303 BHD: 0.377045 BIF: 1664.285005 BMD: 1 BND: 1.35824 BOB: 6.918732 BRL: 3.239768 BSD: 1 BTC: 0.001658952537 BTN: 66.7716 BWP: 10.44955 BYN: 1.9317 BYR: 20026.25 BZD: 2.003485 CAD: 1.315362 CDF: 976.003512 CHF: 0.970299 CLF: 0.024942 CLP: 660.9122 CNY: 6.670311 COP: 2911.736667 CRC: 550.991395 CUC: 1 CUP: 24.728383 CVE: 98.237901 CZK: 24.06994 DJF: 177.6895 DKK: 6.640365 DOP: 46.14923 DZD: 109.20114 EEK: 13.946275 EGP: 8.876718 ERN: 15.345 ETB: 22.18501 EUR: 0.89055 FJD: 2.047283 FKP: 0.771235 GBP: 0.771235 GEL: 2.31522 GGP: 0.771235 GHS: 3.989695 GIP: 0.771235 GMD: 42.59622 GNF: 9085.73 GTQ: 7.521723 GYD: 205.929 HKD: 7.756197 HNL: 22.84758 HRK: 6.675303 HTG: 65.352987 HUF: 272.4474 IDR: 13078.15 ILS: 3.760562 IMP: 0.771235 INR: 66.684569 IQD: 1165.1165 IRR: 30073 ISK: 114.4302 JEP: 0.771235 JMD: 127.627199 JOD: 0.709036 JPY: 100.997801 KES: 101.19139 KGS: 68.521502 KHR: 4094.055 KMF: 438.793335 KPW: 899.91 KRW: 1102.923325 KWD: 0.301276 KYD: 0.824873 KZT: 338.062999 LAK: 8108.6975 LBP: 1509.98835 LKR: 146.360001 LRD: 91.75 LSL: 13.69269 LTL: 3.062908 LVL: 0.624468 LYD: 1.380564 MAD: 9.715581 MDL: 19.74908 MGA: 3052.593333 MKD: 54.86438 MMK: 1240.295 MNT: 2254.463333 MOP: 7.991731 MRO: 355.854167 MTL: 0.683602 MUR: 35.430863 MVR: 15.28 MWK: 718.233316 MXN: 19.76579 MYR: 4.118866 MZN: 77.150002 NAD: 13.66729 NGN: 313.263 NIO: 28.97315 NOK: 8.115266 NPR: 106.6434 NZD: 1.38045 OMR: 0.384972 PAB: 1 PEN: 3.353345 PGK: 3.16725 PHP: 48.0975 PKR: 104.802999 PLN: 3.828987 PYG: 5576.745 QAR: 3.641512 RON: 3.962603 RSD: 109.910661 RUB: 64.00919 RWF: 800.581171 SAR: 3.750628 SBD: 7.839816 SCR: 13.19386 SDG: 6.107271 SEK: 8.542465 SGD: 1.358757 SHP: 0.771235 SLL: 5648.5 SOS: 586.352333 SRD: 7.73675 STD: 21844.6 SVC: 8.747333 SYP: 214.030002 SZL: 13.66699 THB: 34.64227 TJS: 7.877575 TMT: 3.468367 TND: 2.203765 TOP: 2.23775 TRY: 2.962368 TTD: 6.698899 TWD: 31.35474 TZS: 2181.12 UAH: 25.97589 UGX: 3385.153333 USD: 1 UYU: 28.50672 UZS: 2991.175 VEF: 9.977606 VND: 22330.95 VUV: 105.893334 WST: 2.5135 XAF: 584.351655 XAG: 0.05081571 XAU: 0.00075126 XCD: 2.69902 XDR: 0.71484 XOF: 586.950754 XPD: 0.001488 XPF: 106.378 XPT: 0.000882 YER: 250.204 ZAR: 13.69108 ZMK: 5253.075255 ZMW: 10.037938 ZWL: 322.387247"

var find = function(curr_name){
  var ind = data.indexOf(curr_name)
  var res = ""
  if( ind > -1 ){
    for(var i = ind + 5; i < data.length && data[i] != " "; i++){
      res += data[i]
     }
    
  }
  return res
}

console.log(find("AED"))
```

---

### Alternative:

A less complicated alternative, would be to run a script to convert your `currency.txt` to a `currency.json`. Then when you get the data on your client side a simple `var parsed_data = JSON.parse(data)` and you could simply do `parsed_data["AED"]` to get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

try this simple solution

```
$(".currency-target").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "currency.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            var CurrVal = $('.currency-target :selected').val();
            data = data.split("\r\n");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                element = data[i].split(": "); //element[0] as key and element[1] as value
                if (CurrVal == element[0]) {
                    alert(element[0] + "=>" + element[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript is a client side language and has no file process